# Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, 4 дня назад, данный код(ниже) правильно работал не выдавая никаких ошибок (Код работал с VK API), но вот сегодня я заметил что ко всем параметрам вк потребовал указывать версию.

```
method_url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?'
data = dict(v='5.71', access_token=access_token, owner_id='-' + group_id, offset=1, count=1)
response = requests.post(method_url, data)
final_data = json.loads(response.text)
vapi = final_data['response'][1:]
for vphoto in vapi:
    post_id = vapi[0]["attachments"]['photo']['post_id']
    print(post_id)
```

Так вот, я указал версию, но теперь выдается ошибка

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

json который выдается при запросе:

```
{
"response": {
"count": 1701,
"items": [{
"id": 1988,
"from_id": -156603484,
"owner_id": -156603484,
"date": 1517916183,
"marked_as_ads": 0,
"post_type": "post",
"text": "#artist_jonfawkes #clothes #cute #female #hug #human #humanized #impliedshipping #lookingatyou #safe #simplebackground #smiling #starlightglimmer #sunsetshimmer #whitebackground",
"can_edit": 1,
"created_by": 213468131,
"can_delete": 1,
"can_pin": 1,
"attachments": [{
"type": "photo",
"photo": {
"id": 456240981,
"album_id": -7,
"owner_id": -156603484,
"user_id": 213468131,
"photo_75": "https://pp.userap...404/fCJY9Uc0hIQ.jpg",
"photo_130": "https://pp.userap...405/9_AVxZnLRYo.jpg",
"photo_604": "https://pp.userap...406/Ys5I6sFER6A.jpg",
"width": 500,
"height": 500,
"text": "",
"date": 1517916183,
"post_id": 1988,
"access_key": "b64678f96af461dfa7"
}
}]
}
}
```

Comment: По ключу `'response'` лежит словарь, к словарям нельзя принимать сечения (`[1:]` в этом выражении `final_data['response'][1:]`).

Comment: @insolor а как тогда принять?

Comment: Что именно принять? Вы пытаетесь убрать из словаря первый элемент, но у словаря нет "первого" элемента, для него вообще гарантируется фиксированный порядок ключей. Понятно, что вы хотите что-то убрать, но что?

Comment: Мне нужно получить параметр post_id, поэтому я раньше убирал response. Но если есть способ который будет напрямую брать параметр post_id без удаления, то я бы хотел узнать данный способ

Comment: final_date['response']['items'][0]['attachments'][0]['photo']['post_id'] - если не напутал скобки

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы **напутали с типами**.

Это говорит Ваше исключение `TypeError`.
А именно у Вас в `final_data` находится ещё один **словарь** с ключами *items* и *count*, а словари, в свою очередь, не поддерживают *слайсы(slices)*
Решение - брать, соответственно, этот самый словарь `final_data['response']['items'][1:]`.

Также я лично советую Вам использовать библиотеку [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api). Там очень удобный инструментарий, который, однако, можно было бы ещё дополнить.
Также хочу добавить, что в объектах, которые возвращает *requests.get(...)*, существует метод `json` => Вам не нужно использовать библиотеку `json`:

```
final_data = response.json()
```